# Unable to understand [-t 0] inside shell script

Tags: shell

[This browser gist](https://gist.github.com/318247) by defunkt github user starts with this shell expression

```
if [ -t 0 ]; then ...
```

What is the meaning of this line of code?

**UPDATE:** could you also explain why i need this check before doing anything else?

For the sake of completeness, here is the entire little script (it allow to pipe text to the default browser):

```
 if [ -t 0 ]; then
  if [ -n "$1" ]; then  
    open $1
  else
    cat <<usage
Usage: browser
       pipe html to a browser

$ echo '<h1>hi mom!</h1>' | browser
$ ron -5 man/rip.5.ron | browser
usage

fi
else
  f="/tmp/browser.$RANDOM.html"
  cat /dev/stdin > $f
  open $f
fi
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- `[` and `]` invokes `test`
- `-t` makes the `test` test a file descriptor to see if it's a terminal
- `0` is the file descriptor for STDIN.

So that says

```
if STDIN is a terminal then ...
```

#### Motivation

I'd have to read the whole script to know for sure, but usually it's because the script wants to do something visually slick like clear the screen, or prompt interactively.  If you're reading a pipe, there's no point in doing that.

#### Detail

Okay, let's examine the whole script:

```
# If this has a terminal for STDIN
if [ -t 0 ]; then
  # then if argument 1 is not empty
  if [ -n "$1" ]; then  
    # then open whatever is named by the argument
    open $1
  else
    # otherwise send the usage message to STDOUT
    cat <<usage
Usage: browser
       pipe html to a browser

$ echo '<h1>hi mom!</h1>' | browser
$ ron -5 man/rip.5.ron | browser
usage
#That's the end of the usage message; the '<<usage'
#makes this a "here" document.
fi  # end if -n $1
else
  # This is NOT a terminal now
  # create a file in /tmp with the name
  # "browser."<some random number>".html"
  f="/tmp/browser.$RANDOM.html"
  # copy the contents of whatever IS on stdin to that file
  cat /dev/stdin > $f
  # open that file.
  open $f
fi
```

So this is checking to see if you're on a terminal; if so it looks for an argument with a file name or URL.  If it *isn't* a terminal, then it tries to display the input as html.

Answer (score 2):

From the ksh manual (true for bash too).

```
-t fildescriptor    
   True, if file descriptor number fildes  is open and associated with a terminal device.
```

So file descriptor 0, is std input.

Your code asks, essentially, are we running in a interactive mode, or are we in a batch mode.

I hope this helps.

Comment: @shelter why do I have to distinguish between interactive and batch inside the script?

Comment: look at what is happening inside of the block defined between that `if [ -t 0 ] ; then .... what is this code doing ... ; fi` That is the reason. You may be sourcing rc files that are only meant to load aliases and functions, that are only useful on the command line. (That is the most common use of that test). Contrast that to when you ar running a script from a crontab, there will be no terminal associated with the script. Good luck.

Answer (score -2):

This is very useful to check if a shell script is called by a real user using a terminal or if it was called by a crontab or a daemon (in this case the stdin won't exist).

if [ -t 0 ]     --->> if there is a stdin connected (normally a keyboard)

Comment: Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up instead of repeating the same information.