# Bindsym does not execute i3wm command

Tags: bash, i3

This shortcut does not work in i3wm. It's supposed to show the window list of open apps.
Nothing visible happens, when keyboard shortcut is pressed.
`bindsym $mod+space exec bash -c "/home/george/./dmenu-i3-window-jumper.sh"`

However the script runs fine from terminal.

The bash code for the script:
https://github.com/minos-org/minos-desktop-tools/blob/master/tools/dmenu-i3-window-jumper

Comment: works for me, with the exact same script -- perhaps its a permission problem or something wrong with the path you're using on configuration file...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a two side issue

First some small config stuff:

1. I think you got an extra dot in there as `./` in that context just represents the folder preceding it (i.e: `/home/george`)
2. You can use the `$HOME` variable as a stand in for your home folder, i3 will pick it up
3. I would argue there is really no need for the `bash -c`, since your file has both a `.sh` extension and a `#!/bin/sh` header on the first line, which means you just need to give it execution permissions with `chmod +x` and it will run with bash anyways.

So in synthesis, you gotta

```
chmod +x /home/george/dmenu-i3-window-jumper.sh
```

so the script can be run without calling bash directly,
and your bindsym could be simplified to

```
bindsym $mod+space exec "$HOME/dmenu-i3-window-jumper.sh"
```

And then there is the script stuff:

You see, around line 44 the script checks to see if the [STDIN is in a terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8949099/13632818), if its not then it tries to pipe a file to the arg array

```
if [ ! -t 0 ]; then
    #add input comming from pipe or file to $@
    set -- "${@}" $(cat)
fi
```

This seems to be the main problem, since you're not running the command in a terminal and you're not giving it a file either.

Your options are A: changing the `if` so it will always pass an empty string to the argument array

```
if [ ! -t 0 ]; then
    #add input comming from pipe or file to $@
    set -- "${@}" ""
fi
```

or B: create a dummy file with `touch ~/dummy` and then pass it to the script on the bindsym

```
bindsym $mod+space exec "$HOME/dmenu-i3-window-jumper.sh < $HOME/dummy"
```

Both seem to work fine on my setup, good luck!